# Dropbox iOS SDK in-app drop-in?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api

I'm building an iOS app where users can select files from Dropbox. I successfully made it possible to select a file from Dropbox using the [Chooser](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/ios) but I have 2 additional wishes / questions:

- Is it possible to show the chooser inside the app s a modal viewcontroller? And not redirect you to the Dropbox app? The authentication box does this in the iOS simulator, but on a device it also rips you out of the app.
- Is it possible to select multiple files?

> ```
> - (void)addFilesFromDropbox
> {
>     [[DBChooser defaultChooser] openChooserForLinkType:DBChooserLinkTypeDirect >fromViewController:self completion:^(NSArray *results){
>     if([results count]){
>         NSLog(@"got results %@", results);
>         NSLog(@"link 0 = %@", [[results[0] link] absoluteString]);
>     } else {
>         NSLog(@"no results");
>     }
> }];
> ```
>
> }

PS: It needs to be iOS7 compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- No, it's not currently possible to show the Chooser in the calling app, as the Chooser itself is actually only built into the official Dropbox app.
- No, the Dropbox for iOS Chooser doesn't currently support multi-select.

We're tracking both of these as feature requests though.

Comment: Any indication as to how soon these features will be re-added?

Comment: @kyleplattner These features didn't previously exist in the Dropbox iOS Chooser, but in any case I don't have a timeline for if/when they would be implemented.